# Filter columns with renderers but without an index

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, grid, renderer

I'm adding a column like so in `_prepareColumns()` method of a class that extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid`:

```
$this->addColumn('status', array(
    'header' => $this->helper->__('Status'),
    'width'  => '20px',
    'renderer' => 'namespace_modulename/adminhtml_renderer_status'
));
```

It doesn't have an `index` and the values for this column are being shown properly in the grid but I am not able to filter because filtering needs a column in `select` statement to exist.

How can I filter a custom column that its value is returned from a renderer and could be anything?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to use the `'filter_condition_callback'` key. You should start by searching for `'filter_condition_callback'` occurences in the core code and you will find some example.

For example, in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Page/Grid.php`.

Briefly, you have to write something like

```
'filter_condition_callback'=> array($this, '_filterWhatYouWantCondition')
```

and create a protected function `_filterWhatYouWantCondition`

Comment: `filter_condition_callback` filters the collection. But I don't have them in collection.

Comment: Well, a filter on a grid will be the result of a collection that has been filtered.  As you are in the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` block, you necessarily have a collection that you can get with `$this->getCollection()`. I guess you will have to find a way to filter this collection using the value returned by your renderer.

Comment: The problem is I'm using some renderers that return things that don't relate to current collection. They receive `$row` which is an instance of `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item` and return something that isn't in collection. So I can't use collection to filter the results.

Comment: Well, maybe you could modify the collection (in the `_prepareCollection` method for example) in order to put your "unrelated infos" in it. And then, you will be able to filter this collection depending on this "unrelated infos". It sounds tricky but I have no better idea.

Comment: May you please show an example?

Comment: I realized that I could reformulate my last comment by : you should add an index to your collection that will let you filter as you wish. By "adding an index", I mean you should use some join (`$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(....`) in order to retrieve your unrelated infos. I have no interesting example because it depends really on what kind of unrelated infos you are trying to retreieve. Another way to say it could be : you won't be able to filter a grid collection if the data you want to filter is not a part of your collection.

Comment: That's the main issue. The title also says *without an index*. I can't do joins because I've many columns using a renderer the same way.